# How can I keep a vector in the same order after removing an element in Python

Tags: python, list, vector

I know this seems like such a simple question, but when I go to remove the last element of my vector it reorders my vector and won't keep 0 as the last element.

> vec = [1, 1, 0, 1]
>   vec.remove(vec[3])

The remaining vec is [1, 0, 1] when I wanted it to stay in order as [1, 1, 0]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec = [1, 1, 0, 1]
vec.remove(vec[3])
```

`vec[3]` is `1`, so you are removing the first element whose value is `1`, i.e., the first element. The remaining elements are `[1, 0, 1]`. No reordering has been done. This would have been obvious if you had used a wider variety of values in your list.

You want one of these:

```
vec.pop(3)
del vec[3]
```